# Case-insensitive unicode search in mysql?

Tags: java, mysql

My bad, while working with special charecters i came up with storing the text in unicode format in DB(mysql)..all the special charecters were saved properly but unlucky when i starting doing text search in mysql i found that my search is not case-insensitive...

I have googled and found we have to do case-folding, but my issue is neither i have lower case unicode saved..

Just saw in postgress we can do regex search with unicode incase-sensitive search wondering if anything there in mysql...??

Comment: Look for a collation for a table and column to be searched in (look `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`). Alter column definition and set complementary case-sensitive collation, or specify the collation for the column on the query immediately.

Comment: @Akina i see ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 table level, so even the columns collation should be utf8_general_ci isn;t ? if i am not wrong _ci means case-insensitive right ?

Comment: [example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f878069660d024e91408fc97f38fb9b0)

Comment: @Akina my data is saved in unicode format like this..\u0048\u00F8\u006A\u006C\u0075\u006E\u0064\u0020\u004D\u002E\u002C\

Comment: *my data is saved in unicode format like this..\u0048\u00F8\u006A\u006C\u0075\u006E\u0064\u0020\u004D\u002E\u002C\* This is NOT MySQL unicode string literal - MySQL does not know such format. It is the value representation produced by some client software.